# tab bars and NIB files

Tags: iphone, xcode, tabs, uitabbarcontroller

I’ve seen simple tab bar projects created with and without .XIB files, but in both cases still using the interface builder. I must admit, i have had more success without the .XIB.
 
In the examples without the nib, the user enters the class that each of the tabs references in the inspector.  In these examples the programmer has deliberately not created the .XIB file, and the .XIB name is left blank in the inspector
 
What is the rational behind this? , and what is considered a better method?
 
Also,when i experiment using the .XIB method i find i can not have the mainWindow.xib and any other .XIB on the screen at the same time?.  How do you overlay them (purely to get an idea of how it will look) on the interface builder? Is it a setting thing, a bug, or am i misunderstanding something? This particular issue is hindering me a bit in the use of nibs and tab bars
 
I really want to understand what's going on here, can somebody help?

Answer (score 0):

*Go to thenewboston.com and watch tutorials for iphone development.*

or

*Just go to Youtube, and search for iPhone development tutorials using nib files (or ) .xib files.*

These should give you a good start !